# Select text between two patterns with awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed, macos

I would like to select the text between two patterns as follows.

Here is the input:

```
Blalala
'Omfoem From 
balanf PAT1 This is the
text that I want
to get PAT2: apples
Whatever: oranges
```

Here is the output I would like:

```
This is the
text that I want
to get
```

I have tried using this script:

```
awk '/^.*PAT1/{flag=1; next} /.*PAT2/{flag=0} flag' file1.txt
```

But it only outputs the following:

```
text that I want
```

I am missing the parts of the text that are on the same line as the patterns.

I am using OSX.

Comment: Can "PAT1" and "PAT2" occur more than once in your input text? Can "PAT1" occur between a previous occurrence of itself and "PAT2" (e.g. "foo PAT1 bar PAT1 baz PAT2")?

Comment: You are mostly there. You need to do a bit more when you detect pat1 and pat2. Work on one at a time. What do you need to do after you set `flag=1`?

Answer (score 4):

A GNU* `awk` variant, just make `PAT2` the record separator `RS`, `PAT1` the field separator `FS` and print the last field `NF`, making sure that the output is not the result of a repetition of `RS`

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="PAT2"; FS="PAT1"}NF>1{print $NF}' file1
 This is the
text that I want
to get 

 This is another text that I want
to get DONE
```

*Noted @EdMorton

Answer (score 0):

This, with GNU `sed`, as ugly as it is, I think does the trick:

```
sed -e 's/PAT1/\nPAT1\n/' -e 's/PAT2/\nPAT2\n/' file | sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{//!p}'
```

---

Take PAT1 and PAT2 and and add newlines at beginning and end:

```
sed -e 's/PAT1/\nPAT1\n/' -e 's/PAT2/\nPAT2\n/'

Blalala
'Omfoem From 
balanf 
PAT1
 This is the
text that I want
to get 
PAT2
: apples
```

---

Print the text between PAT1 and PAT2:

```
sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{//!p}'

 This is the
text that I want
to get
```

Comment: Thanks! I have adapted the script to make it work in OSX: gsed -e 's/PAT1/\nPAT1\n/' -e 's/PAT2/\nPAT2\n/' file.txt | sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{//!p;}'

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that you where on OSX. Glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU [`grep(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)

```
grep -zoP "(?s)(?<=PAT1 )(.*)(?= PAT2)" file
```

Tests

```
$ cat file
Blalala
'Omfoem From
balanf PAT1 This is the
text that I want
to get PAT2: apples
Whatever: oranges

$ grep -zoP "(?s)(?<=PAT1 )(.*)(?= PAT2)" file
This is the
text that I want
to get
```

From [`grep(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) man page

> ```
> -z, --null-data
>   Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by  a  zero  byte  (the  ASCII NUL  
>   character) instead  of  a  newline.  Like the -Z or --null option, this option can be 
>   used with commands like sort -z to process arbitrary file names.
>
> -o, --only-matching
>    Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part 
>    on a separate output line.
>
> -P, --perl-regexp
>    Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression (PCRE, see below).  This is highly 
>    experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
> ```

Regex explanation:

`(?s)` activate `PCRE_DOTALL`, which means that `.` finds any character or newline.

Uses a Positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=PAT1 )` and Positive lookahead assertion `(?= PAT2)` which causes to only print the capture group `(.*)`.

Caveats of this solution:

As stated by @bushman this only works if there only exists in the file a single occurrence of the two patterns.

Comment: This works in the single case but is greedy of there is more than one `PAT2`

Answer (score 0):

With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk 'sub(/.*PAT1 */,""){f=1} f{if ( sub(/ *PAT2.*/,"") ) f=0; print}' file
This is the
text that I want
to get
```

The above works for the sample input you provided, if you have other input in a different format that this doesn't work for (e.g. nested start/end strings or a start string after an end string on the same line) then please edit your question to show that.